# How to Alias SQL column name with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a stored procedure (SQL Server) from get value where @classtype is a parameter, I want to when classtype = p then classType value come from table but column name English or Other base on classtype, I am trying below code for get data but get error for:

> AS not supported.

```
select
  col
  , col1
  , CASE WHEN @classtype ='P' THEN classType AS 'English' ELSE classType as 'Other' END, col4
from my_table
```

Thanks.

Comment: A column name is static not doing dynamic. Unless you use dynamic SQL - but why would you? You can use any column name you like in your front end

Comment: Sample date and desired results would make your question much clearer.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What results are you trying to produce? Aliases are the names *the developer*, ie you, gives to result columns. It makes no sense defining them based on conditions that can only be evaluated after the query execution. If you want a different name, write a different name

Comment: Are you trying to format the results for display to users or exporting to files? That's the job of the client application, not SQL.

Comment: Store Procedure return a DataTable and this DataTable column name show my HTML table with Dynamically as DataTable column Name. as per requirement i add New column in procedure  then it's show in my HTML table, No need any development on front side.

Comment: @shafaetjsr how did you get on? You have solutions below...

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IF` statement to return a different resultset.

```
IF @ClassType = 'P' BEGIN
    SELECT
        col
        , col1
        , classType AS English
        , col4
    FROM my_table;
END; ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT
        col
        , col1
        , classType AS Other
        , col4
    FROM my_table;
END;
```

Or dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(max) = 
'SELECT
    col
    , col1
    , classType AS ' + CASE WHEN @ClassType = 'P' THEN 'English' ELSE 'Other' END + '
    , col4
FROM my_table;';

EXEC sp_execute @Sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @classtype CHAR(1);
DECLARE @alias CHAR(10);
DECLARE @sql CHAR(1000);
SET @classtype = 'P';
IF (@classtype = 'P')
BEGIN
    SET @alias = 'English';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @alias = 'Other';
END
SET @sql = 'select
    col
    , col1
    , classType as ' + @alias +
    ', col4
from my_table';

EXEC (@sql);
```

Comment: A case expression to set the alias variable value would be a lot more concise

Comment: And it's called dynamic SQL not string sql

Comment: And best practice is to use `sp_executesql`

Comment: And best practice would be to use `nvarchar` for most of those variables - `char` is probably ok for `@classtype`

Comment: yes, I just gave an example, and it's not really optimal